# Word for list of things one does not want

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means a list of things I don't want? An *anti-wishlist*?

Answer (score 5):

A term that is widely used in technical or organizational context is **black list**, as opposed to **white list**. Those are also often used as a verb.

Comment: We're talking specifically about a list of things people want to buy, so the term wishlist is very appropriate. In that context a blacklist doesn't seem to be what I need